# MADDPG: reward drops fast after updating ac network

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, deep-rl, ddpg

I'm using MADDPG to do computation offloading. But the reward drops fast once I start sampling from the replay buffer.
[image]

```
class critic(abstract_agent):

    def __init__(self, obs_shape, act_shape):
        super().__init__()
        self.LRelu = nn.LeakyReLU(0.01)
        self.linear_c1 = nn.Linear(act_shape + obs_shape, 64)
        self.linear_c2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.linear_c = nn.Linear(64, 1)

    def forward(self, obs_input, act_input):
        x_cat = self.LRelu(self.linear_c1(torch.cat([obs_input, act_input], dim=1)))
        x = self.LRelu(self.linear_c2(x_cat))
        x = self.linear_c(x)

        return x

class actor(abstract_agent):

    def __init__(self, num_input, action_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
        # self.LRelu = nn.LeakyReLU(0.01)
        self.LRelu = nn.ReLU6()
        self.linear_a1 = nn.Linear(num_input, 64)
        self.linear_a2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.linear_a = nn.Linear(64, action_size)

        self.action_bound = 1.0

    def forward(self, x, model_original_out=False):
        x = self.LRelu(self.linear_a1(x))
        x = self.LRelu(self.linear_a2(x))
        model_out = self.linear_a(x)
```

Below is the network update code:

```
    def agents_train(self, game_step, update_cnt, memory, obs_size, action_size,
                     actors_cur, actors_tar, critics_cur, critics_tar, optimizers_a, optimizers_c, write):
        if (game_step > learning_start_step) and (game_step % learning_fre == 0):
            if update_cnt == 0: print('\r=start training...' + ''*100)
            update_cnt += 1

            for agent_idx, (actor_c, actor_t, critic_c, critic_t, opt_a, opt_c) in enumerate(zip(actors_cur, actors_tar, critics_cur, critics_tar, optimizers_a, optimizers_c)):
                if opt_c == None: continue

                rew = []
                obs, action, reward, obs_ = memory.sample(batch_size, agent_idx)

                for i in range(batch_size):
                    r = reward[i]
                    ar = sum(r)/len(r)
                    rew.append(ar)
                # update critic
                # rew = torch.tensor(reward, dtype=torch.float)
                rew = torch.tensor(rew, dtype=torch.float)
                action_cur = torch.from_numpy(action).to(torch.float)
                obs_n = torch.from_numpy(obs).to(torch.float)
                obs_n_ = torch.from_numpy(obs_).to(torch.float)
                action_tar = torch.cat([a_t(obs_n_[:, obs_size[idx][0]:obs_size[idx][1]]).detach() for idx, a_t in enumerate(actors_tar)], dim=1)
                q = critic_c(obs_n, action_cur).reshape(-1)     # q
                q_ = critic_t(obs_n_, action_tar).reshape(-1)   # q_
                tar_value = q_ * gamma + rew
                loss_c = torch.nn.MSELoss()(q, tar_value)
                opt_c.zero_grad()
                loss_c.backward()
                nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(critic_c.parameters(), max_grad_norm)
                opt_c.step()

                # update Actor
                # There is no need to cal other agent's action
                model_out, policy_c_new = actor_c(
                    obs_n[:, obs_size[agent_idx][0]:obs_size[agent_idx][1]], model_original_out=True)
                # update the action of this agent
                action_cur[:, action_size[agent_idx][0]:action_size[agent_idx][1]] = policy_c_new
                # loss_pse = torch.mean(torch.pow(model_out, 2))
                loss_a = torch.mul(-1, torch.mean(critic_c(obs_n, action_cur)))

                opt_a.zero_grad()
                # loss_t = 1e-3 * loss_pse + loss_a
                loss_t = loss_a
                loss_t.backward()
                nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(actor_c.parameters(), max_grad_norm) 
                opt_a.step()
```

Here are my train parameters:

```
batch_size = 64
gamma = 0.9
lr = 0.01
memory_size = 1024
EPOCH = 1000
STEP = 100
```

Besides, every time I try to increase the batch_size or lr, the actions all change to 'nan'.
Does anybody face the same issue or know the reason?

Comment: reward too big making the gradient too big, too? i just skimmed the codes. try printing the grad before optimizer step, for each epoch. check if grad become Nan too while you're at it. If so, maybe try different reward function with smaller scale?

Comment: Since I need to minimize time consumption, the reward is set as allowed:
```              
            if energy_cost > ED_energy:
                energy_penealty = -1
            else:
                energy_penealty = 1
            if time_cost > time_limit:
                time_penalty = -2
            else:
                time_penalty = 1
            reward = min(1/(time_cost + 1), time_penalty, energy_penealty)
```

Comment: And I try to print the grad, the result is none.

Comment: wait, why does the loss just blowing up then? to the scale of 1e+30? make sure nothings wrong with the calculation.. 

have you backward() before printing the grad?

Comment: sorry, I checked the grad log again, this is part of the print: grad=tensor([[ 1.4188e-06,  1.5014e-06, -1.9357e-04, -1.0162e-04,  1.5669e-06,
         -5.2142e-05,  6.3059e-07,  6.9160e-07, -2.0823e-04, -1.3216e-04

Comment: check what happens to the grads when the scale of the loss gets really big